# Youtube like button like feature

Tags: javascript, html

So, i am developing this website in which the we allow user to like the connet, now the issue i am facing is that if a user clicks on the like button multiple times sometimes the total_like_count either gets increased by more than 1 or decrease by more than one

we are +1 or -1 alternative times when user clicks on like button sometimes 2 request of +1 +1 is made , i want to cancel the first request of +1;
this is the same logic of youtube like button but the number never increased or decreased by more than 1?

anything in your mind please let me know?

Answer (score 2):

When the button is clicked, disable it, update the state, and enable it after the state is updated, In this way only 1 request would be made in 1 time.

Comment: And return the updated state so you can synchronize the UI to the _actual_ state.

Comment: that fixes the GUI issue; there should also be some sanity checks on the backend to avoid maliciously crafted calls